# Fixing block in bottom sidebar

Tags: html, css

I have fixed sidebar

html

```
<aside class="fixed-col">
<div class="fix-wrap cf">
    <div class="fixed-col-inner">
        <div class="menu-side">
        <div class="main-menu-wrap">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="add-article">2</a></li>
                <li class="my-photos"><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li class="add-photos"><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li class="my-works"><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li class="add-works"><a href="#">6</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="slide-li" onclick="return false"></a>
            <span class="line"></span>
            </div><!-- main-menu-wrap -->
            <ul class="second-nav">
                <li class="open-hidden-nav"><a href="#" onclick="return false">11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">13</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">14</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">16</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- menu-side -->
        <ul class="social">
            <li class="facebook"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="vk"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- fixed-col-inner -->
    </div><!-- fix-wrap -->
</aside><!-- fixed-col -->
```

css

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
}

.fixed-col {
width: 290px;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
background: url(../img/menu-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden; 
transition: all .5s ease;
z-index: 50;
}

.fixed-col-closed {
width: 85px;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
background: url(../img/menu-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden; 
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transition: all .5s ease;
}


.fix-wrap {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
min-height: 100%;
}

.fixed-col-inner {
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

.main-nav {
margin: 15px 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
max-height: 78px;
overflow: hidden;
transition: max-height 0.5s;
}



.main-nav li {
display: block;
}

.main-nav li:hover {
background: #4d4d4d;
}

.main-nav li a {
font: 14px/39px "Calibri";
color: #f5f5f5;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
background: url(../img/sprite.png) no-repeat;
background-position: -10px -357.8999938964844px;
padding-left: 30px;
margin-left: 30px;
}

.main-menu-wrap {
padding-top: 25px;
}


.main-menu-wrap span.line {
margin: 12px 30px 0;
background: #51504f;
height: 1px;
display: block;
}

.second-nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

.second-nav li {
display: block;
}

.second-nav li:first-child {
margin-top: 11px;
}

.second-nav li:hover {
background: #4d4d4d;
}

.second-nav li a {
font: bold 16px/39px "Calibri";
color: #f5f5f5;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding-left: 30px;
}

.social {
margin: 30px; 
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
height: 20px;
background: red;
list-style-type: none;
}


.fix-wrap {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
min-height: 100%;
}

.fixed-col-closed-inner {
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}
```

See [JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m3xzw7k9/1/)

I need block `.social` (red block) always in bottom. I try to set `position: fixed` to it, but when I add content (some more menu items) it dont push `.social` below.
How can I fix `.social` in bottom? Provided - if you add more content then the content push it down.

Upd. I cant remove any block from this markup, I cant change positioning of blocks except block `.social`. I can add html markup if necessary

Updt2. I'm sorry, my english is so bad yet.. I need something like sticky footer, when little content - its always in bottom, when more content - content push it down.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning.

http://jsfiddle.net/9d4p3kbj/

```
.social { 
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    list-style-type: none;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 50;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Also added margin bottom to your .second-nav so it doesn't overlap.

You'll notice that now it has full width, if you need to adjust the padding (or margin) wrap it with another div.

http://jsfiddle.net/9d4p3kbj/1/

Comment: Then perhaps i understood your question wrong. Try give an illustration on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm sorry, my english is so bad yet.. I need something like sticky footer, when little content - its always in bottom, when more content - content push it down..

Comment: Look at that please http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/ I need `.social` like sticky footer.

Comment: I suppose everyone's confusion is that what you want is exactly have been demonstrated by all the answers here. The sticky footer is not 'fixed' to the bottom, but absolutely positioned at the bottom to the footer, in the link you sent. Just like what my fiddle has.

Answer (score 0):

With your same HTML, try this CSS

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.fixed-col {
    width: 290px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    background: url(../img/menu-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    z-index: 50;
}
.fixed-col-closed {
    width: 85px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    background: url(../img/menu-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
.fix-wrap {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    min-height: 100%;
}
.fixed-col-inner {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.main-nav {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    max-height: 78px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
}
.main-nav li {
    display: block;
}
.main-nav li:hover {
    background: #4d4d4d;
}
.main-nav li a {
    font: 14px/39px"Calibri";
    color: #f5f5f5;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    background: url(../img/sprite.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: -10px -357.8999938964844px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.main-menu-wrap {
    padding-top: 25px;
}
.main-menu-wrap span.line {
    margin: 12px 30px 0;
    background: #51504f;
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
}
.second-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.second-nav li {
    display: block;
}
.second-nav li:first-child {
    margin-top: 11px;
}
.second-nav li:hover {
    background: #4d4d4d;
}
.second-nav li a {
    font: bold 16px/39px"Calibri";
    color: #f5f5f5;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.social {
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
    width:290px;
    ;
    background: red;
    list-style-type: none;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    padding:10px 0;
    display:block;
}
.social li {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:50%;
    width:140px
}
.so .fix-wrap {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    min-height: 100%;
}
.fixed-col-closed-inner {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.fixed-col-closed-inner .menu-button {
    right: 25px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7hqmu8tr/)

Comment: Fabio, thank you for answer, look at that please http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/ I need `.social` like sticky footer.

Comment: what I did is a sticky footer, not sure what you mean. If you want to see how it acts with content, just look at http://jsfiddle.net/a4gpjhxj/ . If you mean something else and yo already have the code, why don't you use that code? Anyways, at this point I'm not sure what do you need since this is a fixed footer by definition

Answer (score 0):

When I want to put something onto the bottom i do this:

some parent, grandparent or whatever element:

```
position: relative
```

which you already have in your `fixed-col-inner` class.

The element I want to be on the bottom has to be set like this:

```
position: absolute
bottom: 0
```

so do it to your `.social`

Of course, you got a little mess in there to make it working like this. So let's fix it:

1. `fix-wrap` class: change `min-height` to `height`
2. actually, it's working but now your `.social` red box is invisible due to calculated width=0 (due to no real content). You can set `width=100%` but your margin may destroy the look of it. For further help look [here](http://www.ikelin.com/set-css-width-100-percent-minus-padding-and-margin/).